# Django Storages: use 2 media sources

Tags: django, python-django-storages

In my Django APP I use Django Storages and Dropbox API for media files. This are the settings.

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage'
DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN = 'my_token'
DROPBOX_ROOT_PATH = '/my_app/'
```

I want to ADD another storage in Google CDN, keeping Dropbox. Is it possible? Should be something like overriding the `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`?

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

DEFAULT_DROPBOX_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage'
DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN = 'my_token'
DROPBOX_ROOT_PATH = '/my_app/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media_2/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media_2")

DEFAULT_GOOGLE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.google.GoogleStorage'
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_TOKEN = 'my_token'
GOOGLE_ROOT_PATH = '/my_app/'
```

I couldn´t find much info about this dual Django Storages use. Any advice welcome!

Comment: I don't think you can. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: We have an APP for inhouse work, a sort of CRM, there I want to be able to use Dropbox because our staff can access the DB folder directly. Also we have the website which is public, there I want to use Google CDN for media files.

Comment: then its better to have separate projects for these apps.

Comment: @ruddra I guess it´s the way. Thanks.